# How exactly does the fontSize of SVG foreignObject work

Tags: css, svg, font-size, foreignobject

New to SVG, I was trying to use `foreignObject` to put a custom HTML component inside SVG, and I'm very confused about the fontSize.

It seems like the usual CSS like `font-size: 10px` doesn't work the same way here, when I add that style, the font I got is not exactly 10px. Besides, I noticed that the font size changes as the screen width change.

My question is, which factors are affecting the font size here? and how do I get a static style like 14px?

Here's my current code:

```html
<div style="width: 100%">
  <svg class="ProgressBar" viewBox="0 0 120 10">
    <foreignObject height="30" width="50" x="0" y="0">
      <div style="font-size: 10px; color: rgb(135, 144, 162);">
        <div>Text</div>
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: the viewBox of the svg element is `viewBox="0 0 120 10"` meaning the width is 120 units and the height is 100 units. If the width of the svg element is 120 one unit is 1 px. if the widthis bigger one unit is bigger. 1px in the foreign object is 1 unit

Comment: @enxaneta I'm still not clear on this, based on what you said, if I set the width to 100, then the fontSize should scale properly as 1:1, but that's not happened

Comment: set the width of the svg element to 120px

Answer (score 1):

Like any other SVG element, `<foreignObject>` elements are subject to any scaling that the SVG undergoes.

Your SVG has a `viewBox`, so the contents will be scaled.  That includes the `foreignObject` and the text within it.

If you don't want scaling, then remove the `viewBox`.  Or set the SVG `width` and `height` so that the SVG doesn't scale (ie. has 1:1 scale).

For example, the text in the following snippet has a size of 10px.  This is because the `width` has been set to the same value as the `viewBox` width value (120).

```html
<div style="width: 120px">
  <svg class="ProgressBar" viewBox="0 0 120 10">
    <foreignObject height="30" width="50" x="0" y="0">
      <div style="font-size: 10px; color: rgb(135, 144, 162);">
        <div>Text</div>
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I will need to keep the viewBox here so my text can align with another svg element, is there a way to calculate the scaling then?

Comment: Then this question may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043777/how-to-avoid-scaling-of-elements-inside-foreignobjects-of-svgs